# Looping through all items in a MS Access Table and using each as input for a function

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-access

I am trying to figure out the best (an most efficient) way to loop through each record in my MS Access table and use a column of data as an input parameter for a another function.

Please see the code I was using below:

```
Public Sub FL()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("codes")

'Check to see if the recordset actually contains rows
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 'Unnecessary in this case, but still a good habit
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
      
        'Save CPT code into a variable
        CPT = rs!CPT
    
        CMS_Util.psps_util_json ("CPT")

        'Move to the next record. Don't ever forget to do this.
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If

MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rs.Close 'Close the recordset
Set rs = Nothing 'Clean up

End Sub
```

I pulled this code off SO and tried to modify it by my public sub *CMS_Util.psps_util_json* is not running at all. The loop of saving each CPT in the variable works fine and the *CMS_Util.psps_util_json* runs perfect when ran alone.

I believe my first mistake is using a *Do Unitl* loop versus a *For Each* loop but I hit a wall in what I could find.

FYI, the function that it is calling is designed to pull data from an API on CMS.gov and then calls another function that parses the JSON. I do not think that will effect the solution but I wanted to provide all the context I had. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass CPT.  If so, you need to remove the double quotes.  There is also no need for the parenthesis.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Simple mistake and worked perfectly. I am passing the CPT into a variable as the result of the API call is being appended to another table so the 'Codes' table is being used as a limiting criteria more or less. I know this goes against my 'Efficiency' ask but I am still working some details out there. Thanks for the quick reply! How do I mark as resolved?

Comment: You can only flag an answer and this question does not technically have one.  I am glad I was able to help though.

Comment: @BrianMStafford I started to add more variables other than just the CPT and it is now only running the _CMS_Util.psps_util_json_ for the last line in the rs... any idea what could have happened here?

Comment: Not without seeing your revised code.  You could edit the question and add it.

Comment: Maybe it would have something to do with the `"Delete *"` statement at the beginning of every loop! I think I need to take a break haha. Thanks so much, Brian!

Comment: I guess that could be an issue!  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Working with large sets of data in applications slows down execution tremendously.  Rather read the data to an array and work with the data in the array
Something like this :

```
Dim Data_Arry as variant 

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("codes")

Data_Array = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
```

Then work with data in the array, You should be able to assign back using the same logic

PS - I am not sure if my syntax above is correct.